# Warning : no dns servers found android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

when im trying to run an emulator on android studio an error pops up - warning dns servers not found. how can I solve this problem? its on android studio

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please read the guidlines for posting

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are **connected to internet**. That should be the problem.

**explanation** : At startup, the emulator reads the list of DNS servers that your system is currently using. It then stores the IP addresses of up to four servers on this list and sets up aliases to them on the emulated addresses `10.0.2.3`, `10.0.2.4`, `10.0.2.5` and `10.0.2.6` as needed.So it needs internet connection to deal with them.

When starting the emulator at the command line, you can also use the `-dns-server <serverList>` option to manually specify the addresses of DNS servers to use, where `<serverList>` is a comma-separated list of server names or IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same problem few days ago and I am using Wi-fi connection. This is a simple problem.Just set up your wi-fi or LAN connection of primary DNS server 8.8.8.8 and restart your wifi connection. This will solve your problem. This is not an Android emulator problem, this is wi-fi or LAN connection problem. Just set your primary DNS. This is not in-your-computer or laptop problem, this LAN setup or Wi_fi device setup problem.